# Flutter parsing JSON with array

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have troubles with parsing a JSON file with array.

It looks like something like this:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "address": "Address 1"
        },
        {
            "address": "Address 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I tried to parse it with:

```
var response = jsonDecode(res.body);
print(response['addresses']['address'][0]);
print(response['addresses']['address'][1]);
```

But it is not working. Is there any common pattern how this should be?

Comment: It is not working because your code is incorrect. Why do you think that it should work?

Comment: Thank you Captain Obvious :D. I didn't say it should work... I am asking a question how can I correct my code which is a main purpose of this website :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not accessing it the right way. You have a `Map<String,dynamic>` that has a `List<Map<String,String>>` for the key `addresses`.

If you want to access the first two elements of that list, you can do it by doing:

```
var response = jsonDecode(res.body);
print(response['addresses'][0]['address']);
print(response['addresses'][1]['address']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found for dealing with this is to have this website write the JSON parser for me.  Simply copy / paste you JSON into provide field and choose Dart as the language:

[https://app.Quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Your best mapping the data into a class there is a useful website (created by Javier Lecuona) that generates the class for you. https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Here is an example:

```
var parsedJson = jsonDecode(json);
var addressList = ClientAddresses.fromJson(parsedJson);
print(addressList.addresses[0].address);
print(addressList.addresses[1].address);

class ClientAddresses {
  String status;
  List<Addresses> addresses;

  ClientAddresses({this.status, this.addresses});

  ClientAddresses.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['addresses'] != null) {
      addresses = new List<Addresses>();
      json['addresses'].forEach((v) {
        addresses.add(new Addresses.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.addresses != null) {
      data['addresses'] = this.addresses.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Addresses {
  String address;

  Addresses({this.address});

  Addresses.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    address = json['address'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['address'] = this.address;
    return data;
  }
}
```